# Initializing an Empty Table using schema.sql in Spring Boot

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot

I use a table in PostGres for providing authorization in a SpringBoot web app that connects to a PostGres database. I want to initialize this table with a default admin entry if the table is empty. I am doing this from within schema.sql file Here is the code I have attempted so far:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.jdbcauth
(
    username VARCHAR(32),
    password VARCHAR(32) default NULL,
    role VARCHAR(32) default NULL,
    enabled INT default 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(username)
);

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM public.jdbcauth) THEN
    INSERT public.jdbcauth (username, password, role, enabled) values ('admin', 'admin', 'ADMIN', '1');
```

This always fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer':
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException:
Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of resource URL
[file:/home/balajeerc/Projects/IGVDS_WebApp/src/main/resources/schema.sql]:
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM public.jdbcauth) THEN INSERT public.jdbcauth (username, password, role, enabled) values ('admin', 'admin', 'ADMIN', '1'); 
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The SQL script statement that is in error is not the same as the script you are trying to execute in your initialization.  The error must be coming from a different part of your web app.  Posting some code might help.

Comment: @DavidH I am sorry, the error I posted was what I was getting from attempting a slightly different version than the SQL code I posted above. I have updated the post to now show the snippet of SQL I am trying with the error corresponding to that snippet. Having said that, I am sure that the cause of the error is indeed only those two lines in the `schema.sql` file. When I comment those out, the error disappears. Sorry again about the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I finally managed to do what I want:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.jdbcauth
(
    username VARCHAR(32),
    password VARCHAR(32) default NULL,
    role VARCHAR(32) default NULL,
    enabled INT default 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(username)
);

INSERT INTO public.jdbcauth (username, password, role, enabled)
SELECT 'admin', 'admin', 'ADMIN', 1
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT username FROM public.jdbcauth WHERE username = 'admin'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need a "THEN"?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM public.jdbcauth) THEN
    INSERT public.jdbcauth (username, password, role, enabled) VALUES ('admin', 'admin', 'ADMIN', '1');
```

Comment: No, I get the same error. There seems to be something else thats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
    DO
    language plpgsql
    $$
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM public.jdbcauth WHERE username <> 'admin') THEN
            INSERT public.jdbcauth (username, password, role, enabled) VALUES ('admin', 'admin', 'ADMIN', '1');
        END IF;
    END
    $$
```